# Why AngularJS currency filter formats negative numbers with parenthesis?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-filter

[**Live Demo**](http://plnkr.co/edit/yY9HfwCSAx9DdoQlkKIE?p=preview)

Why this:

```
# Controller
$scope.price = -10;

# View
{{ price | currency }}
```

results in `($10.00)` rather than `-$10.00`?

Comment: This is default behaviour. This may help you if you want to change https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=en#!searchin/angular/goldshtein/angular/8mAc7h5NBd4/k6vo6B6HnIQJ

Answer (score 32, accepted):

This is a popular way to represent negative currencies. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_number):

> In bookkeeping, amounts owed are often represented by red numbers, or a number in parentheses, as an alternative notation to represent negative numbers.

You can see in the Angular source code where they do this (`negSuf`/`negPre`):

```
function $LocaleProvider(){
  this.$get = function() {
    return {
      id: 'en-us',

      NUMBER_FORMATS: {
        DECIMAL_SEP: '.',
        GROUP_SEP: ',',
        PATTERNS: [
          { // Decimal Pattern
            minInt: 1,
            minFrac: 0,
            maxFrac: 3,
            posPre: '',
            posSuf: '',
            negPre: '-',
            negSuf: '',
            gSize: 3,
            lgSize: 3
          },{ //Currency Pattern
            minInt: 1,
            minFrac: 2,
            maxFrac: 2,
            posPre: '\u00A4',
            posSuf: '',
            negPre: '(\u00A4',
            negSuf: ')',
            gSize: 3,
            lgSize: 3
          }
        ],
        CURRENCY_SYM: '$'
      },
```

Comment: is there an extensibility point available for overriding this behavior?

Comment: @DMactheDestroyer you can use a decorator, like described in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30122327/1303135)

Comment: @marc, you're right, and thanks!  This is far more elegant than a custom filter.

Answer (score 78):

I know this is an old question, but the accepted answer is only answering *why* this happens, without a concrete solution to the problem. I think the "most correct way" of doing this, is to use a decorator like so:

```
angular
    .module('app')
    .config(['$provide', function($provide) {
        $provide.decorator('$locale', ['$delegate', function($delegate) {
          if($delegate.id == 'en-us') {
            $delegate.NUMBER_FORMATS.PATTERNS[1].negPre = '-\u00A4';
            $delegate.NUMBER_FORMATS.PATTERNS[1].negSuf = '';
          }
          return $delegate;
        }]);
      }]);
```

This is only called once, valid for any filter which depends on it, and you don't need a custom filter for your currency formatting.

Comment: Great answer, works as expected. This should be voted up!

Thanks!!

Comment: when this gets minified I'm having errors 'Unknown provider: aProvider <- a <- $locale <- currencyFilter` Any ideas?

Comment: @JonHarding it seems I missed to inject the delegation properly; according [to this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23946996/how-to-make-angular-decorators-minification-friendly) the decorator's `$delegate` can be provided with an injection-array. I'll edit the answer accordingly.

Comment: @KishoreRelangi yes, just replace `negPre = '-\u00A4'` with `negPre = '\u00A4-'`

Comment: Thanks, this is what i'm looking for.

Comment: Great solution! Thanks

Answer (score 18):

It works better for me by checking negative number:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp');

app.filter('customCurrency', ["$filter", function ($filter) {       
    return function(amount, currencySymbol){
        var currency = $filter('currency');         

        if(amount < 0){
           return currency(amount, currencySymbol).replace("-", "(") + ')'
        }

        return currency(amount, currencySymbol);
    };
}]);
```

Answer (score 10):

Do you mean display -$10.00 rather than ($10.00)?

The default, at least angularJs version 1.2.1 is to display with parentheses. Eg.: ($10.00)).

If so, this is my situation. I created a custom filter for that:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp');

app.filter('customCurrency', ["$filter", function ($filter) {       
  return function(amount, currencySymbol){
     var currency = $filter('currency');         

     if(amount.charAt(0) === "-"){
        return currency(amount, currencySymbol).replace("(", "-").replace(")", ""); 
     }

     return currency(amount, currencySymbol);
  };

}]);
```

So it delegates to the built-in currency filter and "decorates" or "un-decorates" the parentheses.

I couldn't find a way to change $LocaleProvider on the fly. If someone knows please let me know.

cheers
Leonardo Correa

Comment: If you pass in numbers, this line will help: amount = amount + '';. It will convert the number to be a string (with no change made to the actual number. Otherwise charAt causes errors on numbers.

Comment: @Leonardo how do you use this in this example?  would you change `{{ product.discount | currency:undefined:0 }}` to `{{ product.discount | customCurrency:undefined:0 }}` (I'm new to angularJS 1.5)

Comment: @Bowersbros where in the function would you put `amount = amount + ";` ?

Comment: @Chris22 I would put it on line 5 of the function above (just above var currency), this just converts the number to be a string so that charAt works.

Answer (score 6):

Update: Angular 1.4 no longer uses parentheses to indicate negative values but now uses the "-" symbol. Here is a link to a discussion: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/12870

I used the decorator as described by marc to return the .negPre and .negSuf to use the parens.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind keeping the parenthesis and just want a quick and easy way to achieve this
 eg: `-($250.00)` try the following:

```
<ul ng-repeat="data in customers">
  <li>
    Balance: 
    <span ng-if="data.balance<0">-</span>
    <span ng-if="data.balance>0">+</span>
    {{data.balance | currency}}
  </li>
</ul>
```

If you want to remove the `()`, then you can create your own filter or try the other answers.

Answer (score 1):

Edit your angular.js file  around line number **-36180** 
change negPre and negSuf by removing - and putting parenthesis

For Example

**Change From :**

```
"NUMBER_FORMATS": {
"CURRENCY_SYM": "$",
"DECIMAL_SEP": ".",
"GROUP_SEP": ",",
"PATTERNS": [
  {
    "gSize": 3,
    "lgSize": 3,
    "maxFrac": 3,
    "minFrac": 0,
    "minInt": 1,
    "negPre": "-",
    "negSuf": "",
    "posPre": "",
    "posSuf": ""
  },
  {
    "gSize": 3,
    "lgSize": 3,
    "maxFrac": 2,
    "minFrac": 2,
    "minInt": 1,
    "negPre": "-\u00a4",
    "negSuf": "",
    "posPre": "\u00a4",
    "posSuf": ""
  }
]
```

}

**To**

```
"NUMBER_FORMATS": {
"CURRENCY_SYM": "$",
"DECIMAL_SEP": ".",
"GROUP_SEP": ",",
"PATTERNS": [
  {
    "gSize": 3,
    "lgSize": 3,
    "maxFrac": 3,
    "minFrac": 0,
    "minInt": 1,
    "negPre": "-",
    "negSuf": "",
    "posPre": "",
    "posSuf": ""
  },
  {
    "gSize": 3,
    "lgSize": 3,
    "maxFrac": 2,
    "minFrac": 2,
    "minInt": 1,
    "negPre": "(\u00a4",
    "negSuf": ")",
    "posPre": "\u00a4",
    "posSuf": ""
  }
]
```

}