# How to make angular decorators minification friendly?

Tags: angularjs, google-closure-compiler

How to can I make this code that I have minification friendly?

```
MyModule.config(['$provide',function($provide) {
    $provide.decorator("$exceptionHandler", function($delegate,$injector) {
```

I can't seem to do this:

```
  $provide.decorator("$exceptionHandler" , "$delegate","$injector", function($delegate,$injector) {
```

Answer (score 14):

You are missing the `[`. The pattern is the same that you successfully applied for `config`:

```
$provide.decorator("$exceptionHandler" , [ "$delegate","$injector", 
    function($delegate,$injector) {
```