# Angular Js currency, symbol euro after

Tags: javascript, angularjs, currency

How to move the symbol euro from the front of the value to after it?

Example:

`{{product.price | currency : "€"}}`  will produce `€ 12.00`

but I would like `12.00 €`

Comment: as much as I love AngularJS, these every-day-use locale things should either be covered or left out entirely. Just to prepend a $ sign to ONE currency is just useless. This should be localized.

Comment: Further reading on https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/i18n

Comment: For the record, the official writing is € 12.00, not the other way around.

Comment: @Kriem this depends on the country and language. In Ireland and Malta it's € 12.00, on Cyprus as well, however, in Greece, it's 12,00 €. In Germany it's 12,00 €, but in Austria it's € 12,00. See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_and_the_euro#Written_conventions_for_the_euro_in_the_languages_of_EU_member_states)

Answer (score 60):

**You don't have to hack the currency filter!**

AngularJS has a great support for i18n/l10n. The currency filter uses the default currency symbol from the locale service and positions it based on the locale settings.

So it's all about supporting and setting the right locale.

```
<script src="i18n/angular-locale_de-de.js"></script>
```

If you are using `npm` or `bower` all locales are available via the `angular-i18n` [package](https://github.com/angular/bower-angular-i18n).

```
<span>{{ product.price | currency }}</span>
```

will now produce the following output:

```
65,95 €
```

**Supporting multiple localizations**

If you want to support multiple localizations be careful with the currency symbol as it changes to the default currency of the used locale. But `65,95 €` are different to `$65,95`. Provide the currency symbol as parameter to be safe:

```
<span>{{ product.price | currency:'€' }}</span>
```

In `de-de` the output would still be `65,95 €` but if the location is eg. `en-us` it would be `€65.95` (which is despite some other sayings [the correct format to display euro prices in English](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euro_sign#Use)).

To learn more about angular and i18n/l10n refer to the [developer guide](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/i18n).

Comment: Yes.. The position of Euro is not only country dependant but also Locale dependent. A great example is Belgium with Dutch and French. We kept getting bug reports that it should be left, no right... no left! RIGHT.. LEFT!!?!?! OMG.... I left the company since and they still have not decided :>

Answer (score 18):

You can't with the currency filter. You could write your own, or just use the number filter.

`{{(produce.price | number:2) + "€"}}`

Comment: Actually you can. Using angulars i18n support works great with the currency-filter and as expected: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34953870/555274

Comment: it's more simplified way:
`{{produce.price | number:2 }} €`

Answer (score 4):

use this trick.

```
<div>{{product.price | currency : '' }} €</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

The solutions proposed are all dirty.

at first, the filter allow change symbol by add it as parameter:

```
{{product.price | currency : "€"}}
```

but the right way is localize your app as suggested by @Andreas
if you localize your app for example with italian locale setting (it-it) inside your app you need only invoke the filter to obtain the € sign.

```
{{product.price | currency }}
```

Italian locale setting put the Euro sign before the currency value.
You could change che locale value, or much better override them as proposed in the follow linked answer:

[Why AngularJS currency filter formats negative numbers with parenthesis?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17441254/why-angularjs-currency-filter-formats-negative-numbers-with-parenthesis/30122327#30122327)

you could override the locale setting put your currency symbol (\u00A4) as a prefix or suffix for positive value and negative too.

```
app.config(['$provide', function($provide) {
    $provide.decorator('$locale', ['$delegate', function($delegate) {
      if($delegate.id == 'it-it') {
            $delegate.NUMBER_FORMATS.PATTERNS[1].negPre = '\u00A4\u00a0-';
            $delegate.NUMBER_FORMATS.PATTERNS[1].negSuf = '';
            $delegate.NUMBER_FORMATS.PATTERNS[1].posPre = '\u00A4\u00a0';
            $delegate.NUMBER_FORMATS.PATTERNS[1].posSuf = '';
      }
      return $delegate;
    }]);
  }]);
```

so after this instruction the filter:

```
{{product.price | currency}}
```

will produce the follow output

```
€ 12
```

Comment: I have my scenario:
I have multiple order lines and each lines may have different different currencies

Answer (score 2):

Angularjs has a great support for internationalization and localization.
The application of internationalization and localization depends on the scope of your application.
For example if your application only support euro then you need only the localization for euro and does not require all the currency and its formatting.

In such situation (Assuming your situation is similar to above ) you can create an app configuration and set locale as the localization you required using some decorators. A decorator function intercepts the creation of a service, allowing it to override or modify the behavior of the service.

```js
angular
  .module('app', [])
  .config(['$provide', function($provide) {
    $provide.decorator('$locale', ['$delegate', function($delegate) {
      $delegate.NUMBER_FORMATS = {
        DECIMAL_SEP: '.',
        GROUP_SEP: ',',
        PATTERNS: [{ // Decimal Pattern
          minInt: 1,
          minFrac: 0,
          maxFrac: 3,
          posPre: '',
          posSuf: '',
          negPre: '-',
          negSuf: '',
          gSize: 3,
          lgSize: 3
        }, { //Currency Pattern
          minInt: 1,
          minFrac: 0,
          maxFrac: 1,
          posPre: '\u00A4',
          posSuf: '',
          negPre: '(\u00A4',
          negSuf: ')',
          gSize: 3,
          lgSize: 3
        }],
        CURRENCY_SYM: '€'
      }
      return $delegate;
    }]);
  }])
  .controller('appController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.price = 20.55;
  }])
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.6/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="appController">
    Price : {{price | currency}}
  </div>
</div>
```

The above configuration shows all possible values for decimal and currency settings.
You can change according to your requirements at app level.

If you dont want the effect to be in entire application better is to go for a directive

Comment: Thanks for clarifying which pattern is for the decimal and which is for the currency.

Answer (score 1):

I use this solution in my project (in production) in France (**It must ALWAYS show 5.00€, NEVER show €5.00**):

```
<span>Price: {{product.price| currency:""}} €</span>
```

[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/riZswXaZHl8MfeeDBzu6?p=preview)

Please, read the real question of this post (**Angular Js currency, symbol euro after**) before downvote too quickly!!!!!

Comment: In USA, the $ sign is before the number. In Europe the € sign is ALWAYS after the number.=> $5.00 - 5.00 €

Comment: @webdevbyjoss, It must ALWAYS show 5.00€ even in USA.

Comment: @webdevbyjoss, read the question:  `will produce € 12.00, but I would like 12.00 €`

Comment: it depends on the country if euro-sign is before or after. Several countries use the euro-sign before the number!

Comment: @EricSmekens, read the question of this post "Angular Js currency, symbol euro after". In France the euro symbol is after and this is the question posed here by corsaro.

Comment: You first comment is just plain wrong, that's why I commented.

Answer (score 1):

It's quite an old question, it's different these days.. Maybe it was back then aswell..

So if someone else finds this..

But you need to include the correct locale to get the correct currency formatting in the currency filter.

Check the angular documentation, for example dutch currency formatting is € 5,00 While english is 5,00 € and american is €5.00

Comment: Tip: It would have been nice to link to the mentioned section in the angular doc. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Using the `locale` (as explained in the answer in this thread -
 at [Angular Js currency, symbol euro after](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27547680/angular-js-currency-symbol-euro-after#34953870)) seems like the *most* correct way to do it, but it doesn't seem to offer the flexibility to put the currency symbol or name where you want it relative to the value you're referencing to.  If you need to have your currency symbol after your value, you could have a separate `product.currency` field and interpolate that after (or before) your price value.

So if you have `product.price = 40` and `product.currency = '€'`, you could display it as 40 € with `{{product.price}} {{product.currency}}`.  Or € 40 by reversing the fields: `{{product.currency}} {{product.price}}`.

You'd probably want to format the `product.price` values via the decimal pipe if you did that (https://angular.io/api/common/DecimalPipe). - So "40.00 €" would be : `{{product.amount | number:'2.2-2'}} {{product.currency}}`.

fyi - in this case, I'd probably have a separate field `product.currency` and `product.currencySymbol` (e.g. "USD" and "$" respectively), but then you're getting more into the functionality of the `locale` as referenced in the other answer I link above.  But if you need to place the currency name or symbol in a different location relative to the value than what Angular will let you do via its native pipes, and want to use a currency that's specific to a record or set that you're working with without hard-coding its symbol or name on the page (e.g. if you have multiple currencies you're displaying), this is one way to do it dynamically.

Answer (score -1):

You can create a filter :

```
app.filter('euroFormat', function () {
    return function (input) {
        return input+' \u20AC';
    };
});
```

and apply it on your html code with :

```
<span>Price: {{product.price| euroFormat}}</span>
```