# Replacing dots and commas in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-filters

How can I change the decimal that by default is 'dot' by a 'comma' in the filter of currency in AngularJS?

Example:

```
{{10000 | currency}} 10,000.00 ==> 10.000,00
```

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27547680/angular-js-currency-symbol-euro-after - just Googled "angular currrency europe"

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working demo using a decorator, in the configuration block, to modify locale `NUMBER_FORMATS` properties `DECIMAL_SEP` and `GROUP_SEP`. It is called only one time and is valid for any `filter` that depends on it:

```js
angular
    .module('App', [])
    .config(['$provide', function($provide) {
        $provide.decorator('$locale', ['$delegate', function($delegate) {
            $delegate.NUMBER_FORMATS.DECIMAL_SEP = ',';
            $delegate.NUMBER_FORMATS.GROUP_SEP = '.';
            return $delegate;
        }]);
    }])
    .controller('ExampleController', function($scope) {
        $scope.myNumber = 10000;
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="App" ng-controller="ExampleController">
  <p>{{myNumber | currency}}</p>
</div>
```